# Siunitx: alignment, parentheses and font size

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, punctuation, siunitx

I'm trying to align numbers (that are bolded, between parentheses, etc.) by decimal points in table columns while using the `auto-round` option of the `siunitx` package. The following code doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{table-auto-round,input-open-uncertainty=,input-close-uncertainty=,
tableformat=-1.1}
\begin{tabular}{SS}
1.14 & \textbf{-1.15} \\
\footnotesize{(1.34)} & \footnotesize{(1.35)}\\
\textbf{-1.54} & 1.55
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have an answer half-written, but notice a bug in `siunitx`. I'll have to look at that first!

Comment: Ok. I also noticed that using the array package to make the whole second line footnotesize doesn't seem to work either. Is there a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot put stuff inside a group and expect `siunitx` to be able to tell it is a number. For that reason, you should use `\bfseries` rather than `\textbf` to make cell contents bold. This needs `\bfseries` to be 'robust', most easily achieved using the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and its `\robustify` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\robustify\bfseries
\begin{document}
\sisetup
  {
    table-auto-round,
    input-open-uncertainty=,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
    table-format=-1.1
  }
\begin{tabular}{SS}
1.14            & \bfseries -1.15 \\
( 1.34)         & (1.35)\\
\bfseries -1.54 & 1.55
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I'm really not sure what you are up to with `\footnotesize`. Maintaining alignment here looks pretty tough.

Comment: Note: in answering this question, I spotted a bug in v2.4e of `siunitx` which is fixed but will take a few days to propagate around the world, especially given the time of year.

Comment: Thank you again. I wanted to use footnotesize for standard errors of parameter estimates in a regression. Since they are not as important as the estimated coefficients I wanted to report them in smaller size (and in parentheses).

Comment: The parenthesis are no issue, but changing the size is. Setting up an alignment relies on knowing how big the digits are, and so changing the size of the digits (and the `.`) is a disaster. It is possible to set up to get the size to change but the alignment breaks. Moreover, I'd say that it's bad design to alter the size of text in a table. The parenthesis alone should be enough.

Comment: Without the option [detect-all] when calling the package siunitx, the command \bfseries doesn't work (no error, it just doesn't make it bold).

Comment: @Vivi That’s why it’s in: `\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}`. `\sisetup{detect-all}` should work, too.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I can see it is there, but there are other things in that MWE that are not essential for this to work. I was just noting it for future reference (not because I knew it, but because I tried to incorporate this in a document I am working on and it wasn't working. I spent some time trying to figure it out and wanted to save other people from also wasting time).