# siunitx: How to get bold, aligned entries and how to align when units differ in length?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, tabularx

I tried my first steps with `siunitx`, but I have trouble achieving the following in the minimal example below:

1) aligning the entries in the first column with respect to the decimal dot

2) getting a bold entry in the second column

3) getting the entries in the second column aligned according to the decimal dot.

The code is currently not running due to the `\rowcolor` command. I adapted this from the manual `siunitx.pdf`, why is it not working?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx, tabularx, etoolbox, xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\robustify\bfseries% see 7.15 in siunitx.pdf
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.3]S[table-format=1.4]}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a\ (b)$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{col 1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{col 2}\\\hline
    0.05\ (0.1)&\SI{20.64}{s}&\rowcolor[gray]\bfseries\SI{3.0601}{s}\\
    0.1\ \phantom{5}(0.2)&\SI{16.82}{s}&\SI{1.59}{s}\\
    0.3\ \phantom{5}(0.4)&\SI{22.48}{s$^\ast$}&\SI{0.64}{s}\\
    0.4\ \phantom{5}(0.5)&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$-$}&\SI{0.52}{s}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Update**
After Joseph's first suggestion, I changed the table like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx, tabularx, etoolbox, xcolor, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\robustify\bfseries
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ScS[table-format=2.2]lS[table-format=1.4, detect-weight]}
  \toprule
  $a$ & $(b)$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{col 1, unit} & {col 2/\si{\s}}\\
  \midrule
  0.05 & (0.123) & 20.64 & s & \bfseries 3.0601\\
  0.1 & 0.2 & 16.82 & s2 & 1.59\\
  0.3 & 0.4 & 22.48 & s$^\ast$ & 0.64\\
  0.4 & 0.5 & {--} & kg & 0.52\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

My remaining questions are:

1) How can I align the entries of the second column when one of the entries has surrounding parenthesis? [`(0.123)`]

2) Putting the unit in a different column creates a too large spaces between the units and the numbers (especially if some numbers have more digits such as `2.3 kg` vs `1.232525 kg`). Is there a solution which aligns the entries of the `col 1` according to the decimal point but allows entries to be specified by `\SI{}{}` to get proper spacing between numbers and units?

3) `\rowcolor` still does not work, I obtain an `Undefined control sequence` error. Do I need additional packages?

Comment: In general, we like to keep to 'one issue per question'. That means we can give general answers, which are potentially valuable to lots of people, rather than answering . For example, parentheses have come up before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/siunitx-alignment-parentheses-and-font-size

Comment: The `\rowcolor` part is really entirely independent of `siunitx`, so you may want to ask that separately.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph, I realized I need `colortbl` (as mentioned in the manual).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The content of the `S` column should be a number, not an `\SI` or `\num` command. You should then either move the unit to the column header (by division) or use a separate column. The latter approach is only recommended if the units vary down the column, which is not the case here. You also do not need the `\multicolumn` commands as `siunitx` will automatically deal with braced content in `S` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx, tabularx, etoolbox, xcolor,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\robustify\bfseries% see 7.15 in siunitx.pdf
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post={*}]
  S[table-format=1.4,detect-weight]}
  \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a\ (b)$}
      &{col 1/\si{\s}}
      &{col 2/\si{\s}}\\
    \midrule  
    0.05\ (0.1)&20.64 & \bfseries 3.0601\\
    0.1\ \phantom{5}(0.2)&16.82&1.59\\
    0.3\ \phantom{5}(0.4)&22.48*&0.64\\
    0.4\ \phantom{5}(0.5)&{--}&0.52\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that I've used the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to draw proper rules in the table: these are superior to the LaTeX kernel's `\hline`.

---

Adding in the other requirements would take me to something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx, etoolbox, xcolor, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\robustify\bfseries
\centering
\begin{tabular}
  {
    S
    S[table-format = 2.4,input-open-uncertainty=,input-close-uncertainty=,
      input-symbols=()]
    S[table-format=2.2,table-number-alignment = right]
    @{\,}
    s[table-alignment=left]
    S[table-format=1.4, detect-weight]
  }
  \toprule
  $a$ & {$(b)$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{col 1, unit} & {col 2/\si{\s}}\\
  \midrule
  0.05 & (0.123) & 20.64 & \s & \bfseries 3.0601\\
  0.1 & 0.2 & 16.82 & \s\squared & 1.59\\
  0.3 & 0.4 & 22.48 & \s$^\ast$ & 0.64\\
  0.4 & 0.5 & {--} & \kg & 0.52\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

To include `(` ... `)` as part of the number, I've altered the settings such that the two tokens are not read as an uncertainty part but instead as symbols. I've also reserved space for this extra tokens by treating them as 'digits' from the point of view of `table-format`.

To deal with the spacing for a unit, I have used an `s` column (which parses units), and used `@{\,}` to remove the normal LaTeX inter-column spacing and use instead `\,` (a thin space). I've then altered the alignment so that the two parts of the quantity are pushed together.

Comment: Dear Joseph, many thanks for helping. I updated my post and incorporated final questions.

Comment: Use `detect-all` if you also want to retain the typeface and sizing.