# siunitx: Bold single numeric cells

Tags: tables, math-mode, siunitx, bold

I'm struggling to make a single numeric cell in an `siunitx` table bold. (A similar question for making a *whole* column bold is available [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60069/siunitx-how-to-get-bold-aligned-entries-and-how-to-align-when-units-differ-in).)

I want to define a simple macro which I can set for the largest value in a row to make it bold.

A quick MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{times}

\newcommand{\maxf}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
{A} & {B} \\
1.01 & \maxf{11.1}\\
\maxf{2.1} & 1.94 \\
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

(I use `times` because the math font (CM) and text font (Times) are slightly different in my document ... this is just to highlight that need to format numbers in math mode.)

As I understand it, the following line should make `siunitx` listen for bold in math font.

```
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
```

But then I get the following:

[image: bold not aligned]

... the decimals are not aligned in either column.

If I instead try:

```
\newcommand{\maxf}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldmath #1}}
```

...with `boldmath` used in [page 18 of the `siunitx` documentation](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) (have never seen this command before), the numbers do not appear bold.

---

- How can I define a macro (`\maxf`) to make single numeric cells bold in math mode and keep decimals aligned in `siunitx`?
- If this is not possible or convenient, what highlighting options are available? For example, I notice that underlining using `\newcommand{\maxf}[1]{\ensuremath{\underline{#1}}` breaks decimal alignment.

---

**EDIT**, with Joseph's code below, I get the following (no bold):

[image]

**EDIT3** This was because I had an older version of `siunitx` (v 2.3). I later upgraded to version 2.5 and it worked.

---

**EDIT2** I solved my original highlighting needs by shading the cells of the max results instead.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\maxf}[1]{{\cellcolor[gray]{0.8}} #1}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
{A} & {B} \\
1.01 & \maxf{11.1}\\
\maxf{2.1} & 1.94 \\
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough rep to do anything other than leave a new answer, so I apologize if this is out of place. If somebody with more rep wants to repost this as a comment on [Joseph's post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66256/31088), please feel free. I [ran into trouble](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells#comment141131_66256) using the solution posted by Joseph as-is. However, `siunitx` provides a workaround for the problem of mathptmx not providing bold math mode numerals - you can specify `mode=text` in addition to your other `sisetup` options to

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to use `\bfseries`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
{A} & {B} \\
1.01 & \bfseries 11.1\\
\bfseries 2.1 & 1.94 \\
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to set up the font detected *outside* of the first cell, as table cells form groups.

Comment: @JosephWright -- there seems to be something weird going on: Your method works for C Modern, L Modern, mathpazo, txfonts, and the newtxtext/newtxmath font groups, but *not* if the `mathptmx` (Times Roman for both text&math) package is loaded; in the latter case, the `\bfseries` command simply doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: @Mico That depends on how the fonts are set up, and in particular if the font provides proper access to bold math mode numerals _via_ `\boldmath`. If you try this with `mathptmx`, it does not, hence the issue.

Comment: @Mico: `mathptmx` explictly disables `\boldmath`. When using it you should get a warning in the log `Package mathptmx Warning: There are no bold math fonts on input line 25.` One could probably define a "poorbold" mathversion which emboldens only the numbers and letters but if it would work with siunitx depends on how siunitx choose or acknowledge a mathversion. Beside this: `\boldmath` is a command to make all the math in a formula bold and it should be issued *before* the math like this `{\boldmath$a=b$}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's quite true about how `\boldmath` works, and that's internally how `siunitx` sets it (basically `\hbox <font set up>\ensuremath{<content>}`).

Comment: @JosephWright Does siunitx acknowledges only `boldmath` or could I tell it to use a special `\mathversion{fancy}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - many thanks for explaining the situation with `mathptmx`. I was completely unaware of this font not allowing bold in math.

Comment: I need to use `detect-all`: `detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math` was not sufficient, content do not become bold.

Comment: As of 2021, it's not longer necessary to "robustify" `\bfseries`. The answer could be updated to reflect that.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the current year but (obviously) your LaTeX version. For those < 2021, I couldn't reproduce this solution and still needed `\robustify\bfseries` as mentioned in the siunitx manual. Then it worked. @audeoudh: It would be good to know which part you replaced by `detect-all`.

Comment: I also had to use `\sisetup{detect-all=true}` because the proposed solution only resulted in bold numbers but the actual units were still not bold, e.g., the result looked like `\textbf{123} GB`