# siunitx: bold single numeric cells + mathspec

Tags: tables, align, siunitx, bold, mathspec

I need to bold and align numeric values in a table while using both [`mathspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) and [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) packages. I've looked at [siunitx: Bold single numeric cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells) for bold and alignment in a `tabular` environment with the `siunitx` package, however this breaks when specifying `\setallmainfonts(Digits){Helvetica}` with the mathspec package.

The MWE below shows proper numeric fonts in the displayed math (from the "Digits" specification), the `3.060` is properly aligned, the decimal is properly bold, but the digits are not bold. If the `\setallmainfonts(Digits){Helvetica}` is commented, then the table data is correctly bold and aligned, but then the display math digits revert to CM. Does anyone know how to reconcile these two?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts(Latin,Greek)[Ligatures=TeX]{Helvetica}
\setallmainfonts(Digits){Helvetica}

\robustify\bfseries

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.3,detect-weight]}
   \toprule
   {Header 35} \\
   \midrule  
   \bfseries 3.060\\
   100.59\\
   0.64\\
   0.52\\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

This is the number 2.
\[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2 x^{2}_{i} dx \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have "Helvetica Bold" installed?

Comment: Yes, I have Helvetica Bold installed. However, the problem is not unique to this font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, though I think that there may be a bug in the way siunitx interacts with mathspec. It turns out that both the detect-weight and detect-mode options are required to induce the correct behavior -- bold and aligned -- whereas the detect-weight option alone does not.

I discovered the same behavior with italics (don't forget to `\robustify\it`), though the detect-shape option is required here, as opposed to detect-weight. The detect-all option also works, as one might expect, since this is merely a convenience option that sets detect-weight, detect-family, detect-shape, and detect-mode to true.

Below is a MWE and its output. The output shows the following:

- Proper font throughout, including digits in math mode
- Proper font weight and shape in the table
- Proper alignment of the numbers in the table

Note that I specified `table-format=5.4` in order to ensure that proper alignment was not just coincident with a left or right aligned number.

I am not sure why the detect-mode option is required when using mathspec.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox, siunitx, booktabs, mathspec}
\setallmainfonts(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Ligatures=TeX]{Helvetica}

\robustify\bfseries
\robustify\itshape

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=5.4, detect-weight, detect-shape, detect-mode]}
  \toprule
  {Header 35}\\
  \midrule
  \bfseries 3.060\\
  \itshape 100.59\\
  0.64\\
  0.52\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

This is the number 2.
\[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2 x^{2}_{i} dx \]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output]

Comment: Rather than `\robustify\it` *don't* use `\it`, which has been deprecated for more than fifteen years. Use `\itshape`.