# siunitx: how to get bold, aligned and separated in a table?

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have the following siunitxtable:

```
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=6.0, table-figures-uncertainty=5]
S[table-format=6.0, table-figures-uncertainty=5, detect-weight]
S[table-format=2.0]
S[table-format=1.2, detect-weight]
}
\toprule
{algorithm} & {$1$-ply} & {$3$-ply} & {\# $n$-tuples} & {time [days]}\\
\midrule
42-33 (baseline) & 265435\pm8511  & 393289\pm26496 & 5  & 2.35 \\
42-33, CS        & 258616\pm5784  & 432701\pm13005 & 5  & 2.78 \\
42-33-4-22, CS   & 263156\pm27722 & 464836\pm15941 & 10 & \bfseries 4.63 \\
42-33-4-22-3     & 319433\pm2708  & 469779\pm10920 & 12 & 5.06 \\
42-33-4-22-3, CS & 314013\pm7587  & 491398\pm19458 & 12 & 5.47 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

I was able to make 4.63 bold and aligned, but I would like to make some cells of the second or third column bold and aligned as well. `\bfseries` does not work for them. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `\robustify` the `\bfseries` command as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130341/95441). Then it works for any `S` column.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\begin{document}
        \robustify\bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{
                    l
                    S[table-format=6.0,table-figures-uncertainty=5]
                    S[table-format=6.0,table-figures-uncertainty=5, detect-weight]
                    S[table-format=2.0]
                    S[table-format=1.2,detect-weight]
                   }
            \toprule
        {algorithm} & {$1$-ply} & {$3$-ply} & {\# $n$-tuples} & {time [days]}\\
            \midrule
        42-33 (baseline) & 265435(8511)  & 393289(26496)           & 5  & 2.35           \\
        42-33, CS        & 258616(5784)  & \bfseries 432701(13005) & 5  & 2.78           \\
        42-33-4-22, CS   & 263156(27722) & 464836(15941)           & 10 & \bfseries 4.63 \\
        42-33-4-22-3     & 319433(2708)  & 469779(10920)           & 12 & 5.06           \\
        42-33-4-22-3, CS & 314013(7587)  & 491398(19458)           & 12 & 5.47           \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: There probably is no way to make the bolded number the same width as the regular ones? (this I meant by "aligned", actually)

Comment: You can do it (manually) by putting the text in a "box" and then resize it (have a look at [that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13460/scalebox-knowing-how-much-it-scales) question), but that would mean to either change the font size or you will squeeze the font which will most probably not look very well ...