# Number alignment in tables with some values in partial boldface (all but the decimal point)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, bold

I want to align decimal values in a table with some values printed in bold. Just by itself, this is no problem. We can use the [`siunitx`](https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx&ei=FQ3pUtKfDNLv4QTgyYHoDg&usg=AFQjCNGe7FUGLgy4SYeoLRL9Nkj82G6iKQ&sig2=lbUv57xAjOfbuuNL5hnrNg&bvm=bv.60157871,d.bGE) package and `\robustify\bfseries` to do the trick as described, e.g., in [siunitx: Bold single numeric cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells).

However, I would like to keep the decimal point of the bold values in normal weight. This gives an overall more visually pleasing impression. So far I use a crude workaround (`r@{.}l`) in which integer and decimal parts are their own column.

Is there a possibility to arrive at my desired formatting with `siunitx` or some other package, or do I have to continue using my crude workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `siunitx` provides option `output-decimal-marker` that can be used to set a decimal separator that is not bold. The example is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66256/16967) of Joseph Wright for the [cited question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66253/16967).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx}

\newrobustcmd*{\bftabnum}{%
  \bfseries
  \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={\textmd{.}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
  {A} & {B} \\
  1.01 & \bftabnum 11.1\\
  \bftabnum 2.1 & 1.94 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Why redoing the setting at each call?

Comment: @egreg: Trying to be defensive. The OP has to mark the bold numbers in the table anyway. Therefore the setup is put in this markup macro `\bftabnum`. There might be other contexts, where unaligned numbers might be wanted without having a different font for the decimal separator (e.g. a number in a bold text in a `p` column or whatever).

Comment: The instruction `\sisetup` does local settings. It's sufficient to localize it in the corresponding `table` environment.

Answer (score 7):

Tell `siunitx` that your decimal point must be in the normal font. Above is the example in the linked message, below I added the setting for the period in normal font.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx,booktabs}
\robustify\bfseries
\begin{document}

\sisetup{
  detect-weight=true,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
\toprule
{A} & {B} \\
\midrule
1.01 & \bfseries 11.1\\
\bfseries 2.1 & 1.94 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\sisetup{
  detect-weight=true,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  output-decimal-marker=\textnormal{.},
}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
\toprule
{A} & {B} \\
\midrule
1.01 & \bfseries 11.1\\
\bfseries 2.1 & 1.94 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]