# siunitx: Bold single numeric cells with turned off alignment

Tags: tables, math-mode, siunitx, bold

Having a table with numeric values, I want to achieve:

1. Automatically grouping digits into blocks of three
2. Highlight some cells in bold

However, no alignment is needed. To achieve the first, I use the `S` column of siunitx, combined with the `table-parse-only` package option to turn off alignment.

Now I'm struggeling with the second point. The solution from [siunitx: Bold single numeric cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells) proposes the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx}
\robustify\bfseries
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{SS}
1111.11 & \bfseries 1111.11 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But as soon as I add the `table-parse-only` option, the second cell isn't bold anymore. I could also write:

```
1111.11 & {\bfseries 1111.11} \\
```

Then the second cell is bold, but automatic grouping is turned off.

How can I simply create numeric table with automatic grouping and no alignment, that allows me to highlight some cells in bold?

Comment: How big is your table? Can't you just use an `l` column and do `\bfseries \num{11111.11}`? And why do you want to get rid of the alignment? That's the coolest part of the whole thing...

Comment: The size is not important. No matter how big it is, I can always write a short script that inserts the additional code. However, I'm looking for a clean und beautiful solution, and inserting redundant code is ugly. - And I don't want alignment, because it requires me to specify the column width explicitly. I don't want to do this. The columns contain numbers of different length, and I want the column width to be chosen automatically such that it fits the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one-off cells you can always use a `\multicolumn` command such as

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries \num{11111.11}}
```

This can be packaged in to a macro `\tbnum` for convenience:

```
\newcommand{\tbnum}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries \num{#1}}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx}
\robustify\bfseries
\sisetup{table-parse-only,detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=text}

\newcommand{\tbnum}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries \num{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{SS}
  11111.11 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries \num{11111.11}} \\
  11111.11 & \tbnum{11111.11} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to extend your solution so that it works with techniques that allow us to highlight a whole row in bold (e.g. https://texfaq.org/FAQ-wholerow)? I want to avoid adding `\tbnum{x}` to each individual cell, and write `\rowstyle{\bfseries}` only at the beginning of the row.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I have started a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573658/combining-siunitx-with-formatting-commands

Comment: @yannis The OP specifically asked for turning off alignment.