# Combining siunitx with formatting commands

Tags: tables, siunitx

As is common with tables with numeric results, I would like to mark some values
by using `\textbf` (usually the best results obtained). When I try to combine the `S` type
of column provided by `siunitx` with `\textbf`, I loose the decimal separator alignment.
A solution has been given [five years ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262369/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells-with-turned-off-alignment), I have tried it and it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,siunitx,booktabs,tabularx}
\robustify\bfseries
\sisetup{table-parse-only,detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=text}
\newcommand{\tbnum}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries \num{#1}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llXS}\toprule
A&B&C&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Numbers}\\\midrule
bla&bla&bla&0.535\\
bla&bla&bla&0.535\\
bla&bla&bla&0.535\\\midrule
bla&bla&bla&\tbnum{1322.0}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe the answer below will suit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,siunitx,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=text}
%\newcommand{\tbnum}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries \num{#1}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llXS}\toprule
A&B&C&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Numbers}\\\midrule
bla&bla&bla&0.535\\
bla&bla&bla&0.535\\
bla&bla&bla&0.535\\\midrule
bla&bla&bla&\bfseries 1322.0\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! And I would like to add, for those who use mathspec and xelatex like me that among the options of `\sisetup` one has to add also `detect-all` otherwise the font is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would define robust command for `S` cells' contents making bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}   % <-- 
                         
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l l X S[detect-weight,             % <--
                                     mode=text,                 % <--
                                     table-format=4.1]
                            }
    \toprule
A   & B     & C     & {Numbers} \\
    \midrule
bla & bla   & bla   & 0.535\\
bla & bla   & bla   & 0.535\\
bla & bla   & bla   & 0.535\\
    \midrule
bla & bla   & bla   &\B 1322.0  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]