# Proper way to use formatting in tabular with siunitx

Tags: tables, formatting, color, siunitx

My question is similar to [siunitx: aligning numbers by decimal points in tables doesn't work for bolded or italicized numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2766/46718) , except I would like to apply formatting to **a row or a specific cell**, not a whole column. I have not been able to applying the suggested answers to make `siunitx` interpret the bold or color macros.

The section 9.4 of the `siunitx` package documentation says that

> using the e-TeX protected mechanism is the recommended course of
> action to prevent expansion of macros in table cells

but I still don't know how to properly do that. I tried to apply what is proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573662/46718) with no success:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries
\usepackage{siunitx,xcolor}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-inline-weight=text, locale = FR}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l S S}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}  \\
        \midrule
        foo1 & 11.1 & 11.1\\
        foo2 & 222.2 & 222.2\\
        \textbf{foo3}  & \textbf{3.333} & \textbf{3.333}\\
        foo4  & 4 & 4\\
        foo5  & 555.55 & \textcolor{gray}{555.55}\\
        foo6 & 6.00 & 6.00\\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: table example]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As mentioned in the question you link to, you can't use `\textbf` you must use `\bfseries` to apply to the whole cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Joseph Wright comment I made it using `\bfseries` instead of `\textbf`, and `\color` instead of `\textcolor` (with no brackets at all):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,xcolor}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-inline-weight=text, locale = FR}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l S S}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}  \\
        \midrule
        foo1 & 11.1 & 11.1\\
        foo2 & 222.2 & 222.2\\
        \textbf{foo3}  & \bfseries 3.333 & \bfseries 3.333\\
        foo4  & 4 & 4\\
        foo5  & 555.55 & \color{gray} 555.55\\
        foo6 & 6.00 & 6.00\\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]