# problem given by decimal alignment in latex tabu table with bold numbers

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, siunitx, tabu, dcolumn

I'd like to have a table aligned by decimal point. I'm using `tabu` instead of `table` for exploit rowfont because I need row with smaller character. I've read different posts on `dcolumn` and `siunitx` packages but I didn't solve my problem. Here is part of my table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,colortbl,xcolor}

\begin{document} 

\begin{sidewaystable}[]
\begin{center}
\resizebox*{\textheight}{0.70\textwidth}{%
\setlength\extrarowheight{5mm}
\Huge
\begin{tabu}{|c|l|ccccc|ccccccccc|cccc|cc|}
\cline{3-20}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}                                  & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{P1}                    & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{P2}                                                                                             & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{P4}       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}     \\ \hline
    X1                                      & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{X2}   & $\omega^*$ & $\alpha_1$ & $\alpha_0$   & $\beta_1$ & $\beta_2$ & $m$          & $\alpha_{1,d}$ & $\beta_{1,d}$ & $\beta_{1,w}$ & $\beta_{1,m}$ & $\theta_d$ & $\theta_h$ & $\omega_d$ & $\omega_h$ & $a$      & $b$      & $c$      & $\pi$    & $\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{y})$        & $BIC$   \\ \hline
    \multirow{10}{*}{T1}       & M1                        & 0.042      & \textbf{0.304}      & -0.005       & 0.345     & 0.309     & -           & -              & -             & -             & -             & -          & -          & -          & -          & 3.189   & 0.738   & 1.185  & 0.999  & -20939.5 & 41963.7 \vspace*{-6mm} \\ \rowfont{\huge}
                                &                            &            & 0.007      & {[}0.043{]}  & 0.016     & 0.016     &             &                &               &               &               &            &            &            &            & 0.172   & 0.052   & 0.099  & 0.000  &          &         \\ \hline
    \end{tabu}%
    }
    \end{center}
    {\footnotesize Table description.}
    \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Are there any solution? Thanks!!!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please turn your code fragment into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the documentclass and the relevnt packages that are needed to reproduce your issue?

Comment: These are the main packages that I'm using:

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,colortbl,xcolor}

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about the documentclass and why do you use `\Huge` font size? With such a large font size a table with 22 columns will not fit onto a standard page. Using `\resizebox` to scale a table doeas lead to inconsistend sizes and as you can pbserve in your example, an extremely distorted (and unreadable) text. By the way, you can add information to your question by unsing the `edit` button.

Comment: @antonio Where are `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` into tex code?

Comment: The problem is that I have too many columns and rows. With \resizebox I fit the table in one page and \Huge makes the character more "readable". Anyway I will split the table in 2 pages as soon as the decimal point alignment is achieved. Sorry, but I'm a beginner in latex.

Comment: I would strongly advise against the usage of `\resizebox` especially in combination with the `\Huge` font size as I don't see any improved readability:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbwqK.png Instead you might be interested in redesigning your table (e.g. by splitting or transposing).

Comment: Regarding the alignment of numbers in tables with respect to their decimal markers  using the `siunitx` package (especially if one number is bold) see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66256/134144

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You see the table so deformed because it lacks of many rows. In this short table one cannot use \resizebox and \Huge.

Comment: @leandriis I saw tex.stackexchange.com/a/66256/134144 but I didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @antonio: Here is a short excerpt of your table and an example on how you could use the `siunitx` package to horizontally center the numbers: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|
S[table-format=1.3]
S[table-format=1.3]
S[table-format=-1.3]
}
X1 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X2}& {$\omega^*$} & {$\alpha_1$} & {$\alpha_0$} \\ \hline
T1  & M1  & 0.042 & \bfseries 0.304 & -0.005 \\
 &  & & 0.007 & [0.043] \\ \hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks for this short-table example. The problem with my complex table persist, but I will start from your code to solve it. I think that the best way is to simplify the table structure also to have a better pdf view.