# Putting a line underneath a word in tabular

Tags: tables, formatting

I am trying to fix the words under the lines in the headings (for some reason they are stacked next to each other). Furthermore, I dont know why the numbers between brackets do not show in the tables.

Here is the LaTeX code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float, booktabs, makecell, caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]

\caption{\textbf{Estimates for the TVTPs and average TVTP in each regime}}
\label{table:mstvtp_estimation_results}

\centering\scriptsize
\renewcommand{\TPTminimum}{\linewidth}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}
\bottomrule
\specialrule{0.4pt}{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-TVTP}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{MS-DRA-TVTP} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
&  \thead[l]{$S_t = 1$} & \thead[l]{$S_t = 2$} &  \thead[l]{$S_t = 1$} & \thead[l]{$S_t = 2$}  \\
\Xhline{0.5pt}
Constant   & $ \bm{7.000} $ & $ \bm{-0.999} $ & \bm{6.223}             & \bm{2.101}  \\
           & (0.112)        & (0.460)         &  (0.134)     & (0.512)     \\
GDP Growth & $ \bm{1.834} $ & $ \bm{-0.626} $ & \bm{1.147}             & \bm{-0.028} \\
           & (0.659)   & (0.277)              & (0.647)             & (0.291)     \\
FFR        & 0.420     & 0.369                & -0.323            & -0.493                  \\
           & (0.602)   & (0.514)              & (0.748) & (0.544)                 \\
CPI Growth & -0.292    & $ \bm{2.000} $       & -0.327            & \bm{1.141}              \\
           & (0.839)   & (0.597)              & (0.760) & (0.612)                 \\
Avg. p_{11}& 0.928     &                      & 0.922             \\
Avg. p_{22}& 0.993     &                      & 0.934              \\
\Xhline{0.8pt}
\end{tabular}
\medskip

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
 \item Note: This table reports estimates of the MS-TVTP model. Panel (A) presents estimates for the autoregressive coefficient matrix $\boldsymbol{F}$, vector of means during periods of normal interest rates ($\boldsymbol{\mu}_1$) and low interest rates ($\boldsymbol{\mu}_2$), decay parameter $\lambda$ and average transition probabilities $p_{11}$ and $p_{22}$. Panel (B) presents estimates of the logistic function which is used to compute the time-varying transition probabilities. Bold entries denote parameter estimates significant at the five percent level. Standard errors appear in parentheses.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you define a total of 7 columns when you actually only use 5 of them?  Apart from that, you might want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66256/134144 which is about bold numbers in `siunitx`'s columns.

Comment: Do you mean I should change  ``\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}``  into ``\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}`` ?

Comment: That might help to remove unnecessary columns. Nevertheless, your code generates a lot of errer messages that will not be removed by this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. I have replaced `$\bm` with `\bfseries` (and added `\usepackage{etoolbox} \robustify\bfseries` as [discussed here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66256/134144)), removed unnecessary columns and changed some `siunitx` settings. I have also removed the `textbf` command from the caption and used `\captionsetup` from the `caption` package instead. Lastly, I have also commented out some of the commands that changed sizes and spaces (`\scriptsize` and `\tabcolsep`)  as the table perfectly fits into the textwidth without them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float, booktabs, makecell, caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries

\sisetup{input-symbols = {()}, detect-weight=true}

\captionsetup{font=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\caption{Estimates for the TVTPs and average TVTP in each regime}
\label{table:mstvtp_estimation_results}

\centering%\scriptsize
%\renewcommand{\TPTminimum}{\linewidth}

%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{S[table-format=-1.4]} @{}}
\bottomrule
\specialrule{0.4pt}{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MS-TVTP} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{MS-DRA-TVTP} \\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
&  {\thead[l]{$S_t = 1$}} & {\thead[l]{$S_t = 2$}} &  {\thead[l]{$S_t = 1$}} & {\thead[l]{$S_t = 2$}}  \\
\Xhline{0.5pt}
Constant   & \bfseries 7.000 & \bfseries -0.999 & \bfseries 6.223            & \bfseries 2.101  \\
           & (0.112)        & (0.460)         &  (0.134)     & (0.512)     \\
GDP Growth & \bfseries 1.834 & \bfseries -0.626 & \bfseries 1.147             & \bfseries -0.028 \\
           & (0.659)   & (0.277)              & (0.647)             & (0.291)     \\
FFR        & 0.420     & 0.369                & -0.323            & -0.493                  \\
           & (0.602)   & (0.514)              & (0.748) & (0.544)                 \\
CPI Growth & -0.292    & \bfseries 2.000       & -0.327            & \bfseries 1.141              \\
           & (0.839)   & (0.597)              & (0.760) & (0.612)                 \\
Avg. p\textsubscript{11}& 0.928     &                      & 0.922             \\
Avg. p\textsubscript{22}& 0.993     &                      & 0.934              \\
\Xhline{0.8pt}
\end{tabular}
\medskip

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
\item Note: This table reports estimates of the MS-TVTP model. Panel (A) presents estimates for the autoregressive coefficient matrix $\boldsymbol{F}$, vector of means during periods of normal interest rates ($\boldsymbol{\mu}_1$) and low interest rates ($\boldsymbol{\mu}_2$), decay parameter $\lambda$ and average transition probabilities $p_{11}$ and $p_{22}$. Panel (B) presents estimates of the logistic function which is used to compute the time-varying transition probabilities. Bold entries denote parameter estimates significant at the five percent level. Standard errors appear in parentheses.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```