# Using IEEEtran with siunitx's \num{...}

Tags: siunitx, ieeetran

Using the MWE

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{abstract}
    foo \num{12.34} 12.34 bar.
  \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

The First `12.34` does not care about the bold font set by the abstract environment. Why is that and what is the right way to fix it?

Comment: May be you should try `\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}`... See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66256/120578

Comment: Please make it an answer to I can accept it. (I ended up using `detect-all`, and would have expected that to be the default, but it is not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `\sisetup` command in your preamble in order to tell `siunitx` detect the font weight.

This can be done by using the command:

```
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
```

(as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66256/120578))

Or—as you found out yourself—the command:

```
\sisetup{detect-all=true}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all=true}
\begin{document}
  \begin{abstract}
    foo \num{12.34} 12.34 bar.
  \end{abstract}
  shit
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx}  % <---
\begin{document}
  \begin{abstract}
    foo \num{12.34}\,bar or \SI[mode=text]{12.34}{bar} % <---
  \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```