# siunitx: bold font (and asterisk) do not align well in table

Tags: vertical-alignment, siunitx, bold

I am trying to make some cells bold. Some of the cells may have a trailing asterisk which should also be taken into account. I tried the recommendation in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells), but that does not seem to help much in my case. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

As an additional question, I am also wondering whether I can use `\sisetup{}` for every individual table with different values every time, or whether this command sets the global values. If it sets the global values, how can I make sure that the settings only apply to that table?

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hb]
\begin{threeparttable}
\sisetup{table-format=.4,add-integer-zero=false,detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\begin{tabular}{lSSS|SSSS|SS} 
\midrule
prof & -.1746* & .1606 & .1240  & .0556 & .1498* & .2858 * & .1204 & .1545* & .1842* \\
stud & .0005   & \bfseries{.1918} & .0206  & .0281 & .0647 & \bfseries{.3651*} & -.0312 & \bfseries{.1778*} & .0992 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\item* $p<.05$\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

(I didn't bother with vertical lines)

In comparison to your MWE the following changes were done in the following MWE:

- defined is robust command  for command `\B` which is used instead of `\bfseries`
- added is `mode=text`
- redefined is `table-format`
- added  is space for *

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, threeparttable}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}                          %

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hb]
\sisetup{detect-weight,     % <--
         mode=text,         % <--
         table-format=-0.4, % <--       
         add-integer-zero=false,
         table-space-text-post={*} % <--
         }
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l SSS|SSSS|SS}
    \toprule
prof & -.1746* &    .1606 & .1240  & .0556 & .1498* &   .2858*  &  .1204 &   .1545* & .1842* \\
stud & .0005   &\B  .1918 & .0206  & .0281 & .0647  &\B .3651*  & -.0312 &\B .1778* & .0992 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[*] $p<.05$
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what these differences do? That way, I also learn what I am doing. Especially the use-case for mode=text I am wondering.

Comment: @BramVanroy, the bes explanation you can find in `siunitx` package documentation :-). Also, you can comment some option and observe difference in result. Option `mode=text` make width of boldface numbers equal to width of the normal numbers (as used in text).

Comment: Okay, great! A final question: can I use `\sisetup` in different places for different tables in my document? Or is it a global setup?

Comment: @BramVanroy, if you put `sisetup` in preamble, than its settings are global, if you add in `table` than valid just for this table (and overwrite global settings).