# Making selected, isolated siunitx-formatted cells bold in a table

Tags: formatting, siunitx

I want to bold selected, isolated [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en)-formatted cells in a table.

Generally, I do this with `\bfseries` and `\usepackage{etoolbox}`, as suggested in [Joseph Wright's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66256/15622).

However, in the following MWE, the cells with the `\SIrange` commands do not appear to be formatted in bold.  How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family, detect-shape, detect-weight,
  product-units = power,
  list-final-separator = {, and },
  retain-explicit-plus,
  input-comparators = {<=>\approx\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\sim\lesssim\gtrsim}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \bfseries A & \bfseries\numrange[range-phrase=--]{\sim 5}{17} & \bfseries Some words\\
    \bfseries B & \bfseries\numrange[range-phrase=--]{\sim 5}{17} & \bfseries More words\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: The `semibold` option from `libertine` package is overriding this. If you ommit it, `~5-17` is bold and the rest is not semibold but bold, too.