# When bolding a spreadtab calculation, how to make spreadtab and siunitx coexist happily?

Tags: tables, siunitx, spreadtab

I can't find a way to fix this annoying corner case.

In this example, `spreadtab` gives the value for `cell(foo)+cell(bar)` correctly, but `siunitx` does not do its thing if `\bfseries` is being used in that cell, because to make the example compile with `spreadtab`, I'm forced to hide the calculation from `siunitx` (apparently).

The value shown, `20.687` should be `20.69` instead. and the number is misaligned. The decimal point is in the wrong place.

How can I placate both `spreadtab` or `siunitx`?

[Aligning number with siunitx in spreadtab including calculated numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253649/3406) appears to be the same question, but the sole answer does not describe a satisfactory solution.

Can anyone suggest a workaround, please?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Scale=0.93]{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont[Scale=0.93]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=2, detect-weight=true]}}
  tag(foo) 10.343\\
  tag(bar) 10.344\\
  cell(foo)+cell(bar)\\
  \bfseries :={cell(foo)+cell(bar)}\\
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

siunitx uses math to print the numbers, so you need a boldmath font. Either switch to text mode, or define a bold math version:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Scale=0.93]{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont[Scale=0.93]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}[version=bold,FakeBold=2]
\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=2, detect-weight=true]}}
  tag(foo) 10.343\\
  tag(bar) 10.344\\
  cell(foo)+cell(bar)\\
  \bfseries :={cell(foo)+cell(bar)}\\
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code apparently implem. ents "define a bold math version". I'm not sure what the other option, namely "switch to text mode", means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `mode=text`, see the siunitx documentation,

Comment: Also, does this problem correspond to the log file message "Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "TeXGyreScholaMath/B" (it probably doesn't exist)."?

Comment: I tested your example on my system with TeX Live 2020, and it does not fix the issue. Perhaps something was fixed in the version of `siunitx` that you are using? That seems like the most likely possibility. The version of siunitx that is reported in the logs is "Package: siunitx 2020/02/25 v2.8b". What version are you using? The version of `spreadtab` I'm using is 0.5, but I don't think that has changed. I also tried on Overleaf with TeX Live 2020, and it shows the issue there too.

Comment: I as you should expect from me have a current texlive 2021 and use the newest siunitx.

Comment: I confirmed that this works on an local installation of TeX Live 2021. I'm now wondering what changed between the corresponding versions of `siunitx` (assuming that `siunitx` was what changed) to make this work correctly. Would this be suitable for a separate question?

Comment: I also confirmed that it bolds correctly with the `mode=text` option. The two bolds look quite different. I think I prefer the text one. Also, even if the bolding does  not work, the column is correctly aligned in any case, by the TL2021 version.